# GREP for String owned by a certain group

Tags: linux, grep, file-ownership

I need to do something like this

```
grep -R 'MyString' dir/
```

But instead of searching within a directory, I'd like to search all files owned by a specific group. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-group` option of `find` as shown below:

```
find mydir -group mygroup -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep MyString
```

Comment: It's safer to use null-delimited output (by using `print0` and `xargs -0`) so that filenames containing newlines are handled correctly.